# What is this sequence of control characters (M-bM-^TM-^@) (dashes)? How can I transform these?

Tags: escape-characters, typescript, control-characters

I have a 'typescript' file that if i `cat -v` I get the following within the output:

> M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-

These seem to be rendered `─` within the terminal while running the 'typescript'. How can I transform these to an appropriate plain text representation?

Running `sed "s/M-bM-^TM-^@/testing123/g"` on this file does not seem to work.

Here is the whole file:

```
cat -v typescript
Script started on 2018-07-07 19:08:54+00:00
^[[?1049h^[[22;0;0t^[[H^[[2J^[[?25l^[[1;1H^[(B^[[mHello,                                                                                                                              ^[[2;1H^[(B^[[mWorld!                                                                                                                              ^[[3;1H^[(B^[[mM-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@M-bM-^TM-^@^[[4;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[5;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[6;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[7;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[8;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[9;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[10;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[11;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[12;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[13;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[14;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[15;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[16;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[17;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[18;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[19;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[20;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[21;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[22;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[23;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[24;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[25;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[26;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[27;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[28;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[29;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[30;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[31;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[32;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[33;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[34;1H^[(B^[[m                                                                                                                                    ^[[?1049l^[[23;0;0t^[[?12l^[[?25h^[(B^[[m^[[?12l^[[?25h5^M
zsh:1: command not found: k^M

Script done on 2018-07-07 19:08:55+00:00
```

Comment: Please give a bit more context. Which application produces this sequence? Where do you see them? In which kind of program they are rendered as `-`? A terminal emulator? Which one?

Comment: It's from a typescript file. I'm trying to 'hack' the file to display as plain text in a web browser.

Comment: `col` may possibly help?

Comment: **`M-`** is often used to represent *meta* characters (codes 160-255), and `^T`, `^@` are usually representing control/T, and null.  But without some clue of the application and context, there's nothing to go on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that M- is meta and ^ is control, the sequence `M-b M-^T M-^@` represents hex `e4 94 80`. The character `─` you gave is unicode U2500, "BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL". If you line up the bit patterns, you get something like

```
1110 0100  1001 0100  1000 0000 = e4 94 80
   0 0100     1 0100    00 0000 = 2500
```

So this seems to be a multibyte encoding, where the MSBs denote "first byte" and "following byte", but it's not entirely clear how. (Or this guess is wrong, and in reality the encoding is different). This is not UTF-8, and I have no idea what it is.

I'm also not sure if this answers your question, because you already know that this sequence is rendered as a single character, and which character that is. And in the same way you know that, you'd be able to find out other characters.

So without any more information this probably has no real answer.

Comment: Thanks your answer led me to `sed "s/$(echo -ne '\u2500')/testing123/g"` which seems to do the job.

Comment: Close. M-b is e2 not e4, and e2 94 80 is indeed UTF8 for 2500.